# "Index not defined" when using Firebase JSON API

Tags: json, firebase

When running `https://moodtrackerapp.firebaseio.com/moodlogNumbers/simplelogin:40.json?orderBy="userTimestamp"&auth=TOKEN_REMOVED` I get 'no index defined back from the API, even though I have set an index in my rules.

My data structure:

```
"moodlogNumbers": {
    "simplelogin:1": {
        {
            "-Jin5iKQ_thuHueDOTxn": {
                "level": 9,
                "serverTimestamp": 1424639059798,
                "userTimestamp": 1424639059530
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My security rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
      "moodlogNumbers": {
        ".indexOn": ["userTimestamp"],
        "$user": {
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user",
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I also notice that when trying this query from the docs:

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&print=pretty'
```

I get the same result:

```
$ curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&print=pretty'
{
  "error" : "Index not defined"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon your example data and query, the `indexOn` definition should be under the `$user` object, since the `userTimestamp` field is at `/moodlogNumbers/$user/userTimestamp`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "moodlogNumbers": {
      "$user": {
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user",
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user",
        ".indexOn": ["userTimestamp"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the userTimestamp is at `/moodlogNumbers/$user/$pushid/userTimestamp`